# Reading from FIFO in nc (netcat)

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bunch of logs file that I'd like to watch as they get updted. I came up with the script below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if at least one log file is provided
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 /path/to/log/file1 [/path/to/log/file2 ...]"
    exit 1
fi

if -p pipe_log
then 
    echo "Deleting existing pipe"
    rm pipe_log
    echo "Done!"
fi

mkfifo pipe_log

echo "Setting up log publishing"
# Start tail on each log file and pipe to nc in the background
for log_file in "$@"; do
    (tail -n 0 -F "$log_file"  >> pipe_log) &
done
echo "Done!"

echo "Starting server"
(nc -lk -p 12345 -s 0.0.0.0 < pipe_log ) 
echo "Finished"


# Wait for all background processes to finish
wait

rm pipe_log
```

I consolidate the logs by writing the `tail` of each file to a named pipe.
I then publish the consolidated logs with `nc -lk < pipe_log`. But if I try to read the logs with `nc localhost 12345` there is no output.

I am able to read directly from the FIFO with `cat pipe_log` so there has to be an issue with redirecting from the pipe to `nc` that I am unable to nail down.

PS: I am able to narrow down the problem using `strace`. The server `nc -lk -p 12345 -s 0.0.0.0 < pipe_log` goes into a blocking read operation, as is evident from the output os `strace`:

```
strace: Process <id> attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted read ...>
```

I am unable to determine why the read operation is blocking when there is tons of data being written to the pipe.

Comment: The background processes will never finish. `tail -F` keeps running until you kill it.

Comment: The man page for netcat says you can't use `-s` with `-l`.

Comment: @Barmar that's the intention. The background processes keep watching their respective log files and writing to the pipe.

Comment: @Barmar on Ubuntu 20 the man page says:
`-l  Listen for an incoming connection rather than initiating a connection to a remote host.  The destination and port to listen on can be specified either as non-optional arguments, or  with options -s and -p respectively.  Cannot be used together with -x or -z.  Additionally, any timeouts specified with the  -w option are ignored.`

Comment: Sorry, looks like this is a difference between GNU and BSD netcat. https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc says **-l' Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming connection rather than initiate a connection to a remote host. It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z options.**